# Pull out sub property of Object in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a list of communities each of which has a property country.  Country is an object.  I need to pull country out of each community and put into a country array.  Not sure of the best way to go about this:

```
const communities = [
  {
     communityId: 0,
     country: {
       countryId: 10,
       name: "USA"
     }
  },
  {
     communityId: 1,
     country: {
       countryId: 20,
       name: "Canada"
     }
  }
];
```

So I need an array of countries back:

```
[
  {
    countryId: 10,
    name: "USA"
  },
  {
    countryId: 20,
    name: "Canada"
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you can only fetch the country property of all objects, It will return Id & name

Comment: what do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const communities = [
  {
     communityId: 0,
     country: {
       countryId: 10,
       name: "USA"
     }
  },
  {
     communityId: 1,
     country: {
       countryId: 20,
       name: "Canada"
     }
  }
];

const countries = communities.map(community=>community.country)
console.log(countries)
```

ES6's **map()** higher order function returns a new array with whatever upate  we need from array elements.

```
 const countries = communities.map(community=>community.country)
```

Comment: Have made it to work now, My bad brother... instead of using map() , i typed filter(). Happens sometimes :) Do accept and rate please the answer if it helps. Thanks

Comment: filter won't matter, you're still returning communities on a filter as well

Comment: Let me see, I think you are getting the right array now.. Let me cross check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225236/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-positiveguy).